# PHP Login form error Undefined index: active

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html

Hello whenever i press the signin button onmy website i get this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: active in C:\xampp\htdocs\repute-multipurpose-theme-v1.3\theme\login.php on line 14

I was wondering if you guys know how to fix it. I keep reading about an `isset` function, but i tried that on line 14 and it gave another error so it didn't seem to work.

```
<?php
   include("config.php");
   session_start();

   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      // username and password sent from form 

      $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['username']);
      $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']); 

      $sql = "SELECT customer_id FROM customer WHERE email_adress = '$myusername' and password = '$mypassword'";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
      $active = $row['active'];

      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

      // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

      if($count == 1) {

         $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;

         header("location: index2.php");
      }else {
         $error = "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
      }
   }
?>
```

Comment: Flagged as typo. Just add `active` column to your query and then use prepared statements to prevent sql injection

Answer (score 0):

`$row['active']` should be `$row[0]['active']`;
And also you need to define the `active` column in your query

Answer (score 0):

You haven't selected `active` column in your query. You just have `customer_id`:

```
$sql = "SELECT customer_id FROM customer WHERE email_adress = '$myusername' and password = '$mypassword'";
```

Also, you are prone for [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/601524/5447994).

---

In case, you are not aware of [Undefined Index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4261200/5447994) error.